# Potential in origin for given scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> The potential on the shell of a sphere $|r|=R$ is given by $$\phi=\dfrac{\sin \varphi}{7+3\cos^5\theta}$$ What is the potential at the origin?

**Attempted solution**

The mean value theorem for potentials give $\phi(P) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi R^2} \iint_S \phi dS$ where $P$ is the center of a sphere given by $S:|r-P|=R$. This gives, with $P$ as origin:
$\phi(\mathbf{0}) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi R^2} \iint \dfrac{\sin \varphi}{7+3\cos^5\theta} R^2 \sin \theta \: d\theta d\varphi = 0$ since we're integrating $\sin \varphi$ over $\varphi : 0\to 2\pi$. Does this look correct, and is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you have an answer already. The integral of sine is most certainly zero.

Comment: It seems your calculations produce a zero potential for every point in the interior of the sphere and it isn't plausible as the potential is not zero for points in the sphere.

Comment: @RafaBudría I shouldn't have written that $P$ is an arbitrary point on the interior, that was very confusing. It should be clear now. Notice that $\phi$ is unknown if $P$ is not the origin.

Comment: So is. The theorem is valid only for the center of the sphere. All ok.

Comment: @RafaBudría Do you know of any other way without involving the MVT?

Comment: No. I haven't an alternative.